# how to read xml comment from Property in constructor?

Tags: c#, xml-comments

```cs
public class MyClass {
    

    /// <summary>
    ///   My awesome class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="i_a">This is test of A</param>
    /// <param name="i_b">This is test of B</param>
    public MyClass(string i_a, string i_b){
      A = i_a;
      B = i_b;
    }

    /// <summary> This is test of A </summary>
    public string A {get;}

    /// <summary> This is test of B </summary>
    public string B {get;}

}
```

I want to add in *param* the same info as in Properties, of course, without duplication. I tried with:

### Inheritdoc

It does not display the documentation when you are creating the instance.

```cs
/// <param name="i_a"><inheritdoc cref="A" select="summary" /></param>
/// <param name="i_b"><inheritdoc cref="B" select="summary" /></param>
```

### See or see also link

It creates a link to the property, so that it is possible to navigate to it. But this is not what I want.

```cs
/// <param name="i_a"><see cref="A"/></param>
/// <param name="i_b"><see cref="B"/></param>
```

### My goal

I want to see the documentation of the parameter during the constructor of the class like without duplicate the code comment.

```cs
var test = new MyClass() // start entering the parameters I want to see the documentation of each parameter.
```

It is possible?

Comment: `inheritdoc` works only for classes and interfaces. It won't work for method parameters.

Comment: `see` tag's `cref` makes sure that the referenced type exist during compile time

Comment: @PeterCsala: `inheritdoc` works everywhere, not only in classes and interfaces. You can use it at methods, parameters, fields, etc.

Comment: @PeterMacej I did not know it. Thanks for information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. The `inheritdoc` should work anywhere. There are two problems in your solution with `inheritdoc`:

1. The attribute `select="summary"` selects also the <summary> tag itself. And it searches this tag relatively to the current `inheritdoc` location. In your case it searches for param/summary. See the documentation for my tool [VSdocman](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) at https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/inheritdoc.html

So the correct value should be `"/summary/node()"`.

2. I was surprised to find that [inheritdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#inheritdoc) tag now uses `path` parameter instead of the older `select`. It seems that in some contexts both attributes are supported in VS Intellisense and in some contexts (including the `param` tag) only the `path` is recognized.

So your comment should be:

```
/// <summary>
///   My awesome class.
///   Just a proof that old 'select' attribute works here.
///   <inheritdoc cref="A" select="/summary/node()" />
/// </summary>
/// <param name="i_a"><inheritdoc cref="A" path="/summary/node()" /></param>
/// <param name="i_b"><inheritdoc cref="B" path="/summary/node()" /></param>
public MyClass(string i_a, string i_b)
{
    A = i_a;
    B = i_b;
}
```